# Android - Free non-root app to list apps that can be moved to SD

Tags: android, open-source, memory-card

To free space on non-rooted phone I go to `Application Manager` and set Storage option for huge apps like AirBnB to SD card. I noticed that sometimes this setting is reset again to `Internal storage`, so I spend a lot of time trying to find those applications again and set the setting back to `SD card`.

[image: screenshot]

Is there any open source, free app that at least can list apps whose data can be moved to SD card, but not moved. Ideally it may list all apps and show three status:

- App doesn't allow its data to be stored on SD card (bad app if its huge)
- App allows SD card storage, but is not moved (yellow)
- App storage is moved to SD (green)

**UPDATE (June 12)**: `moving app data to SD card` and `moving app to SD card` is the same. I am looking for an open source application that list which apps on non-rooted device can be moved to SD card.

**UPDATE (June 17)**: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=move.app2sd is just what I need, except that it doesn't show which apps are already moved.

Comment: Are you sure you speak of the app's ***data*** being moved to SD card? If the app can deal with data on the SD card, it either does so by default or you can configure it in the app. In either case, an update to the app should not change that. Aren't you rather speaking of the App itself being moved (App2SD)?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is about data. The screenshot is on the phone and there is no easy way to attach it here.

Comment: Very easy way to attach it: hit [edit] and use the button that looks like an image frame. If it for some strange reason doesn't work for you, just upload it to e.g. imgur and link it here, I'll integrate it for you.

Comment: No image button in SE app for Android - https://imgur.com/a/d3ZJNtu

Comment: Oh, didn't realize that. Integrated the screenshot for you. And I'm still of the opinion this refers to the app itself, not the data (the screenshot is of *Settings › (Manage) Apps › "EdX" › Storage,* right?) I've never heard of a (built-in) feature to store an app's *data* on external storage. The only way to do that to my knowledge is using tools like DirectoryBind or Link2SD.

Comment: @Izzy Probably app still remains in main memory, and only storage moved, because Google Play size still shows some Mb for an app. Anyway, after update all apps appear in main memory again.

Comment: App2SD doesn't move the entire app, only major parts, so that fits. And depending on the settings of your device, it may default to main storage for installs ("default install location").

Comment: Edited the question. Didn't find the `default install location` setting in Android 6 phone.

Comment: [Default install location](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=default+install+location+is%3Aa) (on our Android sister site); [App2SD apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_organize#group_1082) (on my site). E.g. [AppMgr III](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd) can do that, but comes with some trackers (Admob, Crashlytics, Firebase).

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=move.app2sd is just what I need, but it doesn't understand when app is already moved.